# Rolling 3 Years of data with desired format

Tags: sql-server

Start Date = 2016-03-01 
End Date = 2019-02-15

I need the query/Function which should retrive the below result based on start and end date. I have a query to frame the result .But i need some query/function to retrive result set in 5 to 10 sec with performance

[image]

Comment: Do not use spaces in column names..

Answer (score 0):

You mean like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE [start date]>='2016-03-01' AND [end date]<='2019-02-15'
```

Am I missing something? This seems too simple to ask as a question

If your problem is performance perhaps consider indexing start and end date columns, and if you're only getting a couple other values from the table include those in the index too.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_table_startdate_enddate  
ON schema.table ([start date], [end date])  
INCLUDE (othercolumn1, othercolumn2);
```

It means that queries like:

```
SELECT othercolumn1, othercolumn2 FROM table 
WHERE [start date]>='2016-03-01' AND [end date]<='2019-02-15'
```

Can be answered from the index without having to connect the index to the table to pull the desired data

If you still can't wrong enough out of it after that perhaps you have a design flaw in your app; pilling a db for a massive amount of data in a tight interval could be solved another way like only emitting events when data actually changes

Comment: Hi @caius,

The above result set have 4 coulms which should be framed at the run time ,where i will pass only start and end date . This Start and End date is not the physical column.

I have one date column in my table ,wherein i should have a query to frame the aove result set with performace.

Comment: We need to see more info then. If you have only one date column how does it store a start and an end?

Comment: Start date and End date should be calclulated using sql function

Comment: See my other answer

Answer (score 0):

It's just occurred to me you're probably looking for a query to generate that result set from nothing. In sqlserver we can use a recursive cte:

```
DECLARE @dateFrom DATE = '2016-03-01'
DECLARE @dateTo DATE = '2019-02-15'

with d as (
        SELECT @datefrom as m
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,reqDate)
        FROM d
        WHERE DATEADD(MONTH,1,reqDate) <= @dateto
    ),
    SELECT 
        CONCAT( 
          DATENAME(MONTH, @dateFrom), ' ',
          CASE WHEN MONTH(d.m) < MONTH(@dateFrom) THEN YEAR(d.m) - 1 ELSE YEAR(d.m) END, '-',
          DATENAME(MONTH, @dateTo), ' ',
          CASE WHEN MONTH(d.m) < MONTH(@dateFrom) THEN YEAR(d.m) ELSE YEAR(d.m) +1 END
        ) as range,
        MONTH(d.m) as month,
        d.m as startdate,--do not use spaces in column names 
       CASE WHEN @dateTo < EOMONTH(d.m) then @dateTo ELSE EOMONTH(d.m) END as enddate --or dateadd 1 month then dateadd -1 day if you don't have eomonth
    FROM d
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same format with your result try it.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2016-03-01'
SET @EndDate = '2038-02-15'

;WITH CTEs AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDate as [Start Date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,[Start Date])
    FROM CTEs WHERE DATEADD(MONTH,1,[Start Date]) <= @EndDate
)


SELECT 
     CONCAT( 
          DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate), ' ',
          CASE WHEN MONTH([Start Date]) < MONTH(@StartDate) THEN YEAR([Start Date]) - 1 ELSE YEAR([Start Date]) END, '-',
          DATENAME(MONTH, @EndDate), ' ',
          CASE WHEN MONTH([Start Date]) < MONTH(@StartDate) THEN YEAR([Start Date]) ELSE YEAR([Start Date]) + 1 END
      ) AS [Range],
    MONTH([Start Date]) AS [Month],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[Start Date],101) AS [Start Date], 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(CASE WHEN [Start Date] <> DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@EndDate),MONTH(@EndDate),1) 
        THEN EOMONTH([Start Date]) 
        ELSE @EndDate 
    END),101) AS [End Date] 
FROM CTEs
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```